# Kitchen shelf placement

Tags: safety, diy-vs-pro, shelf

I've bought a large, wooden kitchen shelf that I wanted to build up onto a wall above the stove, but my roommate said the heat from the stove will destroy the wood, and will become a health and safety hazard.

Is it safe to put the shelf there, or not? It will be very high up, away from the stove.

Comment: Doesn't your stove have a range hood which would prevent such an installation? If not then you should address **that** fire hazard first.

Comment: while cooking 4 things (or whatever's the worst-case) put your hand where the shelf would go. If you can keep it there for several seconds, the wood will be fine.